# Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'like'

Tags: mysql, character

**Mysql Error Msg:**

CALL `TESTSP`(1, 'super_admin','Frank Patterson','','', 1)  Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'like'  0.000 sec

**MySQL DB Setting**

show variables like '%collat%';

collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server    utf8_general_ci

---

show variables like '%char%';

character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    utf8
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\charsets\

`character_set_client` =  utf8
`collation_connection` = utf8_general_ci
`db_collation` = utf8_general_ci

---

**Tested with this also**

SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', tbl.`TABLE_SCHEMA`, '`.`', tbl.`TABLE_NAME`, '` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;') FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` tbl WHERE tbl.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'dbname'

**Please Suggest**

Could you please suggest any solution as I have wasted a lot of time on this issue but no luck. Also, I have changed the setting for Mysql.ini regarding character set.

Comment: Please, update the question with the result of the following query: `SELECT \`character_set_client\`, \`collation_connection\`, \`db_collation\` FROM \`mysql\`.\`proc\` WHERE \`db\` = 'dbname' AND \`name\` = 'TESTSP';`.

Comment: Please check the following:

`character_set_client` =  utf8
`collation_connection` = utf8_general_ci
`db_collation` = utf8_general_ci

Comment: Check [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tYpjHJ8pHBZott3utFHPtY/0).